# What do all the symbols on my coffee lid mean?

Tags: single-serving

I bought a coffee from Caffè Nero in the UK. It came with this lid:

[image]

What do all the letters mean? I'm assuming DECAF could be marked to distinguish a decaf in a large order, but why is it there twice? What about the other letters? What about 19 near the air hole? Why does it say NO LID??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am pretty sure it says NO TL316 LID.  That's the item/stock number for that particular size lid (based on a Google search, also available in black!). There are basically two sets of initials for the same thing Decaf, (C)ream, (S)ugar, (C-S) Cream and Sugar, and then one set has the B for Black.  Presumably these could be grease penciled or highlighted on a large order.

I honestly have no idea on the 19.  It may be some sort of internal tracking mechanism for manufacturing, because other examples from a Google image search have different numbers there.

Comment: It could be 19 fluid ounces which is approx 540 ml

Comment: This particular lid will fit 12, 16 and 20 ounce cups.

Comment: @EdChum It was a regular (UK) sized cup. Although it was Monday morning, a pint of coffee at once is still a bit much for me...

Comment: The C-S for 'cream & sugar' makes no sense: it would be just as easy to tick/check/encircle both the C and S.

Answer (score 0):

19 is most likely a mold number. Used in manufacturing for quality control.

Wow, this thread is old. What about D C M L O on my lid? Decaf, Cappuccino, Macchiato, Latte, O?

Comment: This space is just for answers to the question. If you have a lid with interesting symbols on it, post a new question and show a picture.